# How can I add custom params to junit reports generated through maven Surefire plugin?

Tags: java, maven, junit, maven-surefire-plugin

I am using maven surefire plugin to generate junit reports.

```
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-surefire-report-plugin</artifactId>
<version>3.0.0-M1</version>
```

I have a job configured in Jenkins to run junits which sends an email to entire team on Junit failure.
Now since there are thousands of testases being run and more than 30 team members, I am looking for a way to configure developer/owner name with junits (can be hardcoded through some annotation in testfile or some other way) so that , it could be included in reports and the owner is identified.

Is achieving this possible?

Comment: If I correctly remember there is an option in Jenkins within the extended mail template to make customizations... usually if a build fails it has been done by a particular commit that means this "culprit" will get the build report which can be configured in Jenkins accordingly...

Comment: @khmarbaise you are right. And I am already doing that. And it does cover 80% of the cases. But still there are a few cases, like configuration changes where owners need to fix the junits rather than person chaging the config. I need this configuration in such cases.
( I understand that the real issue is with junits as they shouldn't be dependent on environment but till the time they are fixed, it would be nice to have such a config )

Comment: What do you mean by owners junits ? Code ownership in a team? Sounds bad.. Apart from that and yes a junit test should never depend on an environment cause it's no longer a unit test...